# Let $l(x)$ be the linear approximation of $f(x) = x^{2/5}$ at $a = 32$. Approximation?

Tags: calculus, linear-approximation

I'm still a bit confused on how to figure out linear approximations. What are the basic steps to solving a problem like this? Thanks so much!

**Let $l(x)$ be the linear approximation of $f(x) = x^{2/5}$ at $a = 32$**

What is the linear approximation?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Do you know the following formula ? $f(x)\approx f(a)+f'(a)\cdot (x-a)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tangent line will be the linear approximation

ie,

$$f(x)=x^{\frac{2}{5}}$$

$$f'(x)=\frac{2}{5}x^{\frac{-3}{5}}$$

$$f(32)=(32)^{2/5}=4$$

$$f'(32)= \frac{1}{20}$$

and so the equation of the tangent line L(x) at x=32 is,

$$L(x)=4+\frac{1}{20}(x-32)$$

Comment: Okay, thanks. How did you get that $f'(32) = (\frac{1}{20}) $? One of the closest solutions on the problem is $f(34) approx 4 + (\frac {2^{2/5}}{13}) $? Another option is $f(34) approx 4 + (\frac {1}{7* 2^{3/5}}) $

Comment: @androidguy Do you know that the fifth root of 32 is 2 ? Then $\frac{2}{5}\cdot 32^{-3/5}=\frac{2}{5}\cdot 2^{-3}$. And $2^{-3}=\frac{1}{2^3}=\frac{1}{8}$. In total it is $f'(32)=\frac{2}{5}\cdot \frac{1}{8}=\frac{2}{40}=\frac{1}{20}$.

Comment: Ahh okay, thanks so much.